# Is it possible serialize SplEnum in php

Tags: php, spl

Is it possible serialize SplEnum? I'm trying use SplEnum, but userialized instance has only default value. 
For example:

```
class Test extends SplEnum
{
    const __default = self::A;
    const A = 1;
    const B = 2;
}
```

...

```
$t = new Test( Test::B );
$s = serialize($t);
$t2 = unserialize($s);
```

Variable $t2 is instance of Test but with default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you don't get an expected value after unserialize is that SplEnum is not just a regualar PHP class. It is a kind of hack. The value is kept in its own structure, not in PHP object itself as you can see here

https://github.com/davidcoallier/SPL_Types/blob/master/spl_type.c in method `spl_type_object_new_ex`

They create an internal structure "object"

```
object = emalloc(sizeof(spl_type_object));
```

that holds the value

```
ZVAL_ZVAL(object->value, *def, 1, 0);
```

The `unserialize` function does not know a thing about this internal object and cannot change its value. Hence this peculiar behaviour.

### Update

You might want to use casting in order to preserve the object's value. In your case it could have been:

```
$casted_value = (int) $t;
```

At least an integer is easier to handle.

### Update 2

A working example with working serialization.

```
class Test2 extends SplEnum  implements Serializable 
{
    const __default = 1;
    const A = 1;
    const B = 27;
    const C = 31;

    public function serialize() {
            return serialize ((int) $this);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        $this->__construct (unserialize($serialized));
    }
}
```

Comment: PHP knows its `ZVALs` ;-) The explanation seems not correct to me as you can't serialize/deserialize any `const` by default and you cannot redeclare a const.

Comment: There is the __default property that holds the value. `"O:4:"Test":1:{s:9:"__default";i:2;}"`

Comment: `__default` is a constant, not a property

Comment: If this is a constant, how it ended up in the serialized string?

Comment: I guess it's `SplType::__construct ([ mixed $initial_value [, bool $strict ]] )` generating some `private` properties with the values. I can't reproduce because I don't have `SplEnum`, if I try `serialize` an object with constants, those constants don't get printed in the serialized string. We could further investigate this using reflection classes and see what's *visible* and what can be done. But pretty sure a `const`declared object variable cannot be unserialized because it is const.

Comment: I am not argueing or offending you by the way, it's just that I'm curious about this very specific problem; I'm interested in it! Most people don't even know or use SPL tho I think SPL is really good.

Answer (score 0):

This is not SPL specific, you simply can't serialize constants because they are not a property of an object.

You can serialize any constant if you implement a `__wake()` method **or** implement the `Serializable` interface like shown in the code below.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep

```
<?php
class Test extends SplEnum implements Serializable {
    const A = 1;
    
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array('A' => self::A));
    }
    
    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        // cannot redeclare A when unserializing!
        // This is not SplEnum specific but with every class.
    }
}

$test = new Test;

echo serialize($test);
```